# How to disable the red underline in code blocks in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

So normally I code in VB (don't judge me) but I forked a C# project that codes in the format of:

```
private void SomeFunction()
{
    some code. Note the braces.
    
    if (yada yada yada)    
    {
        blah
    }
    else
    {
       blah blah
    }
}
```

I think this looks noisy when there are a lot of lines of code, and in my coding prefs set the braces to look like this:

```
private void Somefunction() {

    some code.

    if (yada yada yada) {
        blah
    } else {
       blah blah
    }

}
```

I wasn't seeing these red lines until I logged into my VS account in VS and it imported all of my preferences, and now they're under all of the code blocks that follow MY brace prefs.

And now for the life of me, searching through all the settings, ***cannot*** find where to disable these red lines?

[image]

Anyone know where I can toggle these off? This is currently happening in Visual Studio 2022.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was from my favorite VS Extension, DevExpress CodeRush, under the setting "*Structural Highlighting*" in CodeRush's Options.

Setting the option to "*a single vertical line*" is just what I wanted (it was defaulted to "*Horizontal and Vertical Lines*".

[image]

[More info](https://docs.devexpress.com/CodeRushForRoslyn/120387/visualization-tools/structural-highlighting)